# Cannot communicate with ov2640 sensor on ESP32Cam using ZephyrOS

Tags: embedded, esp32, device-tree, zephyr-rtos

I've been trying to use Zephyr RTOS and ov2640 cam sensor. I've found the implementation that allows to use this sensor but using espressif SDK, however, I would like to try this using Zephyr.

In general, there is an ov2640 driver sensor available in Zephyr SDK, but I have difficulties using it. I've properly configured a kernel, enabled the driver, and it compiles, but calling the function "device_is_ready" always returns false.

I've enabled the log subsystem and looking at the logs, it seems that the driver fails at early-stage initialization when it tries to read PID and VER registers - in general it's a first attempt to communicate with the sensor.

Here are the logs that are printed to the console when the driver is being initialized:

```
00:00:01.815,000] <err> i2c_esp32: I2C transfer error: -116
[00:00:01.820,000] <err> i2c_esp32: I2C transfer error: -14
[00:00:01.825,000] <err> i2c_esp32: I2C transfer error: -14
[00:00:01.830,000] <err> ov2640: failed to write 0x1 to 0xff
[00:00:01.830,000] <err> i2c_esp32: I2C transfer error: -14
[00:00:01.835,000] <err> i2c_esp32: I2C transfer error: -14
[00:00:01.841,000] <err> i2c_esp32: I2C transfer error: -14
[00:00:01.846,000] <err> ov2640: failed to read 0xa register
[00:00:01.846,000] <err> i2c_esp32: I2C transfer error: -14
[00:00:01.851,000] <err> i2c_esp32: I2C transfer error: -14
[00:00:01.856,000] <err> i2c_esp32: I2C transfer error: -14
[00:00:01.861,000] <err> ov2640: failed to read 0xb register
[00:00:01.861,000] <err> ov2640: OV2640 not detected
```

The explanation for error codes is as follows:

- -116 -> ETIMEDOUT
- -14 -> EFAULT

The device tree overlay I've created:

```
&pinctrl {
    i2c_cam: i2c_cam {
        pinmux = <I2C0_SDA_GPIO26>,
             <I2C0_SCL_GPIO27>;
        bias-pull-up;
        drive-open-drain;
    };
};

&i2c0 {
    sda-gpios = <&gpio0 26 (GPIO_PULL_UP | GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;
    scl-gpios = <&gpio0 27 (GPIO_PULL_UP | GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c_cam>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";

    ov2640: ov2640@30 {
        compatible = "ovti,ov2640";
        status = "okay";
        reg = <0x30>;
    };
};
```

I don't expect this to be fully working, I would be satisfied if the sensor at least answered with something, then I would know that I'm on the right track, but now it seems that it doesn't respond at all.

I've tested it with Espressif and it works fine.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: The most basic test here is to build the camera example with the Espressif SDK to verify that the camera works at all. If it doesn't work then it's a hardware issue and you're not going to get anywhere with this code.

Comment: I've already done this. Camera is working fine with Espressif SDK

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect external pull-ups 4-10kOhm, i2c should be pulled-up with such registers(internal registers may not work). Also check camera input frequency, OV7670 does not work at all without XCLK connected and does not work with invalid frequencies.